# SQL Server 2012 - Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

Can someone please explain why the below query works? I assume the first DECLARE uses a VARCHAR that's long enough to hold the table name. But why does the second DECLARE use a VARCHAR and why does it's corresponding query need to be wrapped in 'quotes'?

```
USE Northwind

DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(25)=
  (Select top 1 tab.name
  From Sys.tables tab
  Where name not like 'dtproperties'
  and name not like 'sysdiagrams'
  order by tab.name asc)

DECLARE @Output VARCHAR(100) =
  'SELECT COUNT(*) AS [CountOf_' + @TABLENAME + ']
   FROM [' + @TABLENAME + ']'

EXEC(@Output)
```

Comment: You should also be VERY careful with this query. It's not escaping correctly.

Comment: The value of @Output is in type of varchar (text/string) so it need to be wrapped in 'quotes'.

Comment: The first declare statement simply sets a string value to the "tablename", it is like assigning a variable from another variable.
The second declare statement is like assigning constant or a literal value to the variable "Output".. so it should be enclosed with quotes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The datatype of `@TableName` being `VARCHAR(25)` is incorrect (or at least a poor choice). Most objects (Tables, Views, Stored Procedures, Functions, etc) have a datatype of `sysname` which is an alias for `NVARCHAR(128)`. So no, the first DECLARE uses a datatype that is not only *not* long enough, but would also not be able to hold a wide range of otherwise valid Unicode characters.
2. The second DECLARE uses a `VARCHAR(100)` because it is making two possibly bad assumptions:

   1. that there will never be any Unicode characters, and
   2. that the names of the tables will never be more than 62 characters long (that's the amount of characters left after you remove the rest of the characters shown in that query)
3. The query is wrapped in quotes and submitted via the `EXEC()` (i.e. it is Dynamic SQL) since neither the columns nor the tables of a query can be variables.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer pretty much covers it!